# How get the best threshold value by ROC curve

Tags: probability, roc, threshold

I'm working with **unbalanced class databases** and I'm wondering what's the **best practice** to retrieve the **best threshold cutoff** value using **roc curve** ?

I want the best cutoff to maximize my **F1** score.

> I already have a roc curve I'm wondering what the best practice to
>   generate the best threshold cutoff.

Comment: Slippery slope of a question... Please read [this entry](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/67442/67822). If you are using R and want to calculate the values suggested [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/29727/67822), I have it summarized for different packages in my notes [here](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/roc.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any input (threshold) you have one output (F1 score), so, you can try to do a grid search, where you try every possible threshold from 0 to 1 in grid (say, `seq(0,1,by=0.01)`) and see which number maximize the F1 score.

In addition, the finding the best threshold can be also viewed as a one dimensional optimization problem (without using gradient). You can try `optimize` in R. Details can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optimize.html). The difference between grid search and `optimize` is `optimize` is using a "smarter way" to search, e.g., if we see worse results we will not continue on that direction.